# NSTreeController does not respond to reloadData

Tags: cocoa, nstreecontroller

I have a NSTreeController with bindings to a class.

NSOutlineView dirTree binds to the NSTreeController

In particular Outline View Content binds to arrangedObjects

This appears to work well, but I am at my wits end to figure out why it does not respond to reloadData.

The NSTreeController
Key paths are:-

```
Children    subDirectories
Count       numberOfSubDirs
```

These are listed below; numberOfSubDirs returns a simple count of subDirectories (with an added diagnostic display).

```
- (NSArray *)subDirectories {
    if (subDirectories == nil) {
        [self loadSubDirectories];
    }
    return subDirectories;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSubDirs {
    NSArray *tmp = [self subDirectories];
    NSLog(@"numberOfSubDirs %@ %d", [self relativePath], [tmp count]);
    return [tmp count];
}
```

If I call a refresh function which updates the data then calls [dirTree reloadData]; I get the following output:-

```
Reload Data
numberOfSubDirs Shared 7
numberOfSubDirs Adobe 1
numberOfSubDirs bZTree2 0
numberOfSubDirs Ian Documents 25
numberOfSubDirs Library 1
numberOfSubDirs NET 1
numberOfSubDirs TSA 12
numberOfSubDirs Wacom 1
```

If I delete a directory (externally in Finder) and call the refresh function I get the following output:-

```
Reload Data
numberOfSubDirs Shared 6
numberOfSubDirs Adobe 1
numberOfSubDirs bZTree2 0
numberOfSubDirs Ian Documents 25
numberOfSubDirs Library 1
numberOfSubDirs NET 1
numberOfSubDirs TSA 12
numberOfSubDirs Wacom 1
```

NSTreeController calls numberOfSubDirs on the parent "Shared", and is correctly told it now has 6 subdirectories.

However it then queries 7 subdirectories, including the deleted item "bZTree2", and does not refresh the display to show only the 6 which exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTreeController` does not respond to `-reloadData` because it doesn't implement that method. You will get both a runtime exception and a compiler warning if you try to call it on an `NSTreeController` instance.

`NSOutlineView` responds to `-reloadData`, but it won't do anything unless the `NSOutlineView` uses a data source. If you are using `NSTreeController` it won't do anything at all.

Since you seem to be creating a file system view, I highly recommend you go via the data source route rather than using `NSTreeController`, it will save you a lot of trouble.

Apple has some [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/Articles/UsingOutlineDataSource.html) and [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OutlineView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008836) for doing this also.

Comment: I realise my question was incomplete, and I have edited it.
NSOutlineView dirTree binds to the NSTreeController
and I am sending reloadData to NSOutlineView. I assumed that NSTreeController was acting as the data source. It would seem to be strange to have a Controller that didn't allow for updating. I will re-write if I have to, but would still like to understand if is possible using the controller

Comment: OK, but read the rest of my answer. Calling `reloadData` will do nothing if you are using `NSTreeController`, it doesn't make sense to use it unless your outline view is backed by a data source.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I finally get it. NSTreeController would only work if I used its methods to modify the data. The sample was helpful, and I will implement a data source.